# Password field deletes '/' character from password

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Let's say i have a user with the password *te/st*. 
And this markup:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" required>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-click="login(username, password)">Sign in</button>
```

Somehow, the value contained in the ng-model becomes *test*
Why is this happening?

The method in the controller:

```
        $scope.login = function (username, password) {
                console.log("pass:", password);
                authService.login(username, password).then(function () {

                    console.log("auth success. username: ", username);
                },
                 function () {
                     notifications.showError("Login failed!");

                 });
            };
```

Comment: How exactly are you te/sting this?

Comment: Seeing controller would also be necessary

Comment: How is `login` function called? It takes a parameter `password` instead of using `$scope.password`. I'm just guessing here since you aren't sharing complete code

Comment: I didn't face this one before but i am thinking of making directive parsing the text to skip this behavior.

Comment: Can't reproduce with the info you've given. Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gdep5ugg/

Comment: This will be embarrassing but here it goes. I think it was a copy paste problem. I copied the password from a file. I wanted to paste it as a file name, so I can have easy access while testing. While saving the filename, the / character was removed. A filename does not allow that character. Because I did not notice this, I was using another string actually. 

Thank you for your time and interest!

Answer (score 1):

This plunkr shows it does actually work -- the slash char shows up:
https://plnkr.co/edit/tSVFtmSILTR606AZrdH1?p=preview

Here's the entire code for testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" required id="pwd">
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('pwd').value)">click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If you type te/st in the box and click the button you'll see:

[image: plnkr password]

Comment: You are right. In another environment it works.

Comment: @VictorB try this as a test: 
Call encodeURIComponent(password)  -- it will convert the password (te/st) to te%2st and pass it in Just to see if it passes correctly.  You can always decodeURIComponent() later.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to replicate it. Use below code if you have to.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.login = function(username, password){
    $scope.passedUserName = username;
    $scope.passedPassword = password;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" />

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <br/>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">User Name</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Value</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Entered Password" ng-model="password" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-click="login(username, password)">Sign in</button>
  </div>
  <div>
  <p>Passed Username: {{passedUserName}}</p>
  <p>Passed Password: {{passedPassword}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are right. In another environment it works.

Comment: If that is the case then could you create a plunkr to show the problem. It is rather interesting. And what environment are you using?